# Naming an Ngram document after a string. Julia v1.1.1

Tags: nlp, julia, n-gram

I am running Julia v1.1.1 on a windows 10 machine.

I recently went back to update my Julia v0.6.2 code to Julia v.1.1.1 as my code is no longer supported in Julia v0.6.2 anymore.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to name an Ngramdocument after a string, I think the function used to do this was in the TextAnalysis package :

```
name!(Ngramdocument, string)
```

However, recently now that I am trying to update my code to Julia v1.1.1 it is saying that the function is undefined. I was wondering if maybe I was wrong in assuming that the function was defined in the TextAnalysis.jl package or if they changed the name. I have not been able to find documentation of a name change however.

Answer (score 1):

`name!` was changed to `title!`. `title!(Ngramdocument, string)` should work as expected in Julia 1.1.1 with the recent `TextAnalysis.jl` release. You can see the relevant pull request [here](https://github.com/JuliaText/TextAnalysis.jl/pull/135).

While migrating code, if you face such undefined function errors, you may quickly find the changes looking at the commit history of the package repository or using search function on the GitHub repo of the package.

Comment: Thank you! I am still new to coding just started a few months ago so figuring out where to find these changes is still tough. So thanks for the answer as well as an explanation on where to find answers such as these in the future.